# How to sort a list by length and then in reverse alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, key, reverse

For example:

```
a=['a','b','zzz','ccc','ddd'] #before sorting

a=['b','a','zzz','ddd','ccc'] #after sorting

a.sort(key=len)
```

sorts the data but in alphabetical order but How to sort in the list by length and then in reverse alphabetical order ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `reversed` function:

```
a = list(reversed(sorted(a, key=lambda x: (-len(x), x))))

In [301]: a                                                                                                                                        
Out[301]: ['b', 'a', 'zzz', 'ddd', 'ccc']
```

Comment: I updated it, sorry. Now it sorts by "length and then in reverse alphabetical order"

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer and selecting it as accepted answer

Comment: I learned with practice. There is a good book here: https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach useing `cmp_to_key()` from `functools`:

```
import functools

def customsort(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return -1 if len(a) < len(b) else 1
    else:
        if a < b:
            return 1
        elif a > b:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0

def main():
    a=['a','b','zzz','ccc','ddd']
    a.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(customsort))
    print(a)

main()
```

**Output**:

```
['b', 'a', 'zzz', 'ddd', 'ccc']
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the customsort() . And how it gets 2 aurgments and compare with all the elements in list.

Comment: Good question, it should be described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)..

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Comment: how about reverse length and reverse alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `sort()` method. First sort the list descending, then by the length of the values:

```py
#before sorting
a = ['a', 'b', 'zzz', 'ccc', 'ddd']

#after sorting
a = ['b', 'a', 'zzz', 'ddd', 'ccc']

a.sort(reverse=True)
a.sort(key=len)
```